# How to effectively create table using React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, web-frontend

**Description**

I want to create table like this :

[image]

However, I have done it well, but I am doubtful of my code, it seems too complicated and not simple.

Here's my code so far :

```
const FormCreateRole = ({ switches, onChange }) => {
  // Array for table header and its data
  const tableHeader = [
    "No",
    "Menu",
    "Sub Menu",
    "Lihat",
    "Tambah",
    "Ubah",
    "Hapus",
    "Export",
  ];

  const submenu = [
    ["-"],
    [
      "Akun Pengguna",
      "Grup & Kontrol Hak Akses Akun",
      "Antrian Pasien",
      "Rawat Jalan",
    ],
    ["Pemeriksaan Penunjang", "Rekam Medis", "Admisi Rawat Jalan"],
    ["Status dan Penempatan Kamar", "Transfer Pasien"],
  ];

  let i = 1;

  const tableDataMenu = [
    [i++, "Dashboard", submenu[0], "", null, null, null, ""],
    [i++, "Konfigurasi/Pengaturan", submenu[1], "", "", "", "", null],
    [i++, "Layanan Pasien", submenu[2], "", "", "", "", null],
    [i++, "Rawat Inap", submenu[3], "", "", "", "", null],
  ];
  // end Array data

  return (
    <Table className="table-responsive">
      <thead style={{ backgroundColor: "#ECEFF1" }}>
        <tr>
          {tableHeader.map((header, index) => (
            <th
              key={index}
              className="txt-blue-grey-700 base-md text-bold text-center"
              style={{ padding: "0.75rem" }}
            >
              {header}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {tableDataMenu.map((row, idx) => (
          <React.Fragment key={idx}>
            <tr>
              {row.slice(0, 2).map((cell, idx) => (
                <td key={idx} className="text-center">
                  {cell}
                </td>
              ))}
              <td>
                {row[2] && (
                  <div>
                    {row[2].map((sub, idx) => (
                      <div key={idx} className="mb-3">
                        {sub}
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                )}
              </td>
              {row.slice(3).map((cell, idx) => {
                return (
                  <td key={idx}>
                    {row[2] &&
                      row[2].map((subIdx) => {
                        if (cell !== null) {
                          return (
                            <div key={subIdx} className="mb-3 text-center">
                              <Form.Check
                                type="switch"
                                id={`${subIdx}-${idx}`}
                                label=""
                                checked={switches[`action${idx}`]}
                                onChange={onChange}
                              />
                            </div>
                          );
                        }
                      })}
                  </td>
                );
              })}
            </tr>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
};
```

**Question**

Can you help me in efficiently, readable and effectively creating the code for the table? I apologize, I am currently learning a lot and struggling to master React JS.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a code review for your working code.

I don't think I would change much, if any, as this is a pretty straight forward table rendering in React.

Usually dynamic rendering is used for dynamic data and actually it seems weird that you are using dynamic rendering for static content.

Some minor suggestions:

1. Pyramid of doom: since the code is long and you have the pyramid of doom due to .jsx hierarchy (and not logic paths), you could separate the tbody into its own component. You could then either pass the required variables down to the tbody component using prop drilling or react context.
2. The hard coded table data is being re-rendered every time the function is rerendered. Maybe use `useMemo` for this entire component, since it currently doesn't have any dependencies and really only needs rendered once.